# how to call an instance method inside a static method?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I know how we can usually call a regular method of the class or static method of a class but I just realized I have no idea how to call a regular method of the class inside a static method :|

something like this

```
module.exports = class Notification {
  parsing_html(order) {
   // some parsing
  }


  static async send_notification(_id){
    const order = await Order.findOne({ _id });
    this.parsing_html(order);
  }
};
```

I figure with `this` or not, still does not work.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Comment: You cannot call an instance method from a static one. Not without an actual *instance*. Static methods are, by definition, not related to any one instance. Why is this method static at all? Seems like that's wrong. Either that, or `parsing_html` should be static.

Comment: @VLAZ got it, thanks :D I was playing around and just came into mind to try it out, but didn't get anything after googling :|

Comment: Then I suggest reviewing what static methods are. What you're trying to do is fundamentally not possible. Again, not without changing what you actually want to do. If `Notification` was a singleton or otherwise you could get ahold of an instance of the object, then you can use it in the static method call. Or you can always instantiate the object but that'd be a code smell suggesting the design or interface is wrong.

Comment: One way to solve it would be to call `new this().parsing_html(order)`. However this is bad practice and does not work if the constructor requires parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript at runtime there is no such thing as an "instance method" or "static method". The whole class / static syntax is just a shorthand. Javascript OOP is based on prototypes and constructors.

```
class Abc {
   constructor() { ..constructor code.. }
   test() { ... }
   static staticTest() { ... }
}
```

is just a shorthand / more intuitive syntax for:

```
function Abc() { ..constructor code.. }
Abc.prototype.test = function() { ... }
Abc.staticTest = function() { ... }
```

Both codes are EXACTLY the same at runtime.

Therefore you can always call `Notification.prototype.parsing_html` from everywhere in your code. But there is a catch: the keyword `this` will always reference the object that the method is called on (the object directly before the dot, see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this ), with the exception of arrow functions. In this case `Notification.prototype` will be `this` for the function call which might lead to unexpected behaviour. You can set what is `this` by using `call` or `apply`: `Notification.prototype.parsing_html.call(yourThisObject, order);`

```
module.exports = class Notification {
  parsing_html(order) {
   // some parsing
  }

  static async send_notification(_id){
    const order = await Order.findOne({ _id });
    Notification.prototype.parsing_html(order); 
  }
};
```

Comment: "*at runtime there is no such thing as an "instance method" or "static method"*" - then how else do you call methods that are available to instances and methods that live on the class object (constructor) itself?

Comment: This is really a matter of your viewpoint. I would call them "static method" and "instance method" based on what I want them to be. But they are actually just methods. There is no difference at all in how they work.
Consider this: `class A { instanceMethod() { console.log("A") } } A.sameMethod = A.prototype.instanceMethod; new A().instanceMethod(); A.sameMethod();` what do you call that method? It is both an instance and a static method.

Comment: They are what we call them. The reference `A.sameMethod` is a static method, and `(new A).instanceMethod` is an instance/prototype method. Sure, they both resolve to the same function object, but a "method" is more than that.

Comment: Exactly. Its how you use it and what it actually is that makes it an instance method. What you call a static method is actually an instance method of the constructor because the constructor is an instance of `Function extends Object`. It depends on you point of view in javascript. Which is fundamentally different to how it works in OOP languages like Java / C# etc.

Comment: This answer is exactly correct and should not have been downvoted.